# Collect most occurring unique values across columns after a groupby in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe

```scala
val input = Seq(("ZZ","a","a","b","b"),
("ZZ","a","b","c","d"),
("YY","b","e",null,"f"),
("YY","b","b",null,"f"),
("XX","j","i","h",null))
.toDF("main","value1","value2","value3","value4")
input.show()

+----+------+------+------+------+
|main|value1|value2|value3|value4|
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  ZZ|     a|     a|     b|     b|
|  ZZ|     a|     b|     c|     d|
|  YY|     b|     e|  null|     f|
|  YY|     b|     b|  null|     f|
|  XX|     j|     i|     h|  null|
+----+------+------+------+------+
```

I need to group by the `main` column and pick the two most occurring values from the remaining columns for each `main` value

I did the following

```
val newdf = input.select('main,array('value1,'value2,'value3,'value4).alias("values"))
val newdf2 = newdf.groupBy('main).agg(collect_set('values).alias("values"))
val newdf3 = newdf2.select('main, flatten($"values").alias("values"))
```

To get the data in the following form

```
+----+--------------------+
|main|              values|
+----+--------------------+
|  ZZ|[a, a, b, b, a, b...|
|  YY|[b, e,, f, b, b,, f]|
|  XX|          [j, i, h,]|
+----+--------------------+
```

Now I need to pick the most occurring two items from the list as two columns. Dunno how to do that.

So, in this case the expected output should be

```
+----+------+------+
|main|value1|value2|
+----+------+------+
|  ZZ|     a|     b|
|  YY|     b|     f|
|  XX|     j|     i|
+----+------+------+
```

`null` should not be counted and the final values should be `null` only if there are no other values to fill

Is this the best way to do things ? Is there a better way of doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [udf](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs.html) to select the two values from the array that occur the most often.

```scala
input.withColumn("values", array("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"))
  .groupBy("main").agg(flatten(collect_list("values")).as("values"))
  .withColumn("max", maxUdf('values)) //(1)
  .cache() //(2)
  .withColumn("value1", 'max.getItem(0))
  .withColumn("value2", 'max.getItem(1))
  .drop("values", "max")
  .show(false)
```

with `maxUdf` being defined as

```
def getMax[T](array: Seq[T]) = {
  array
    .filter(_ != null) //remove null values
    .groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length) //count occurences of each value
    .toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2) //sort (3)
    .map(_._1).take(2) //return the two (or one) most common values
}
val maxUdf = udf(getMax[String] _)
```

Remarks:

1. using an udf here means that the whole array with all entries for a single value of `main` has to fit into the memory of one Spark executor
2. `cache` is required here or the the udf will be called twice, once for `value1` and once for `value2`
3. the `sortWith` here is [stable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2e2f65a201b0b06e01a39fec4ae232c5b94efcca/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L627) but it might be necessary to add some extra logic to handle the situation if two elements have the same number of occurences (like `i`, `j` and `h` for the main value `XX`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try without udf.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy('main).orderBy('count.desc)

newdf3.withColumn("values", explode('values))
  .groupBy('main, 'values).agg(count('values).as("count"))
  .filter("values is not null")
  .withColumn("target", concat(lit("value"), lit(row_number().over(w))))
  .filter("target < 'value3'")
  .groupBy('main).pivot('target).agg(first('values)).show

+----+------+------+
|main|value1|value2|
+----+------+------+
|  ZZ|     a|     b|
|  YY|     b|     f|
|  XX|     j|  null|
+----+------+------+
```

The last row has the null value because I have modified your dataframe in this way,

```
+----+--------------------+
|main|              values|
+----+--------------------+
|  ZZ|[a, a, b, b, a, b...|
|  YY|[b, e,, f, b, b,, f]|
|  XX|              [j,,,]| <- For null test
+----+--------------------+
```